# How do I maintain a JavaScript class library in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010

I'm new to Visual Studio. In short what I would like to do is to avoid copying my often used .js utility classes to my projects all the time.

Back when I used Flash a lot, I could put all my class files (utilities, etc.) in a folder somewhere, and then I can tell Flash about that folder so that in any project, I can refer to the classes without having to copy them individually in my project folder (through import statements).

Is there a way for me to use this work flow for JavaScript development in VS2010? Or is there any other best practice I should follow for this?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, you can set up a project template.  In that template, you could include all your basic project settings and files.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zfzh36t7.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Would that allow me to maintain a single location for my classes ? e.g If I update my classes does the template use that updated version ?

Comment: You'd have to update the file in the template.  it would use the updated file for all new projects...

Answer (score 0):

I put my javascript (at least js code that can be commonly used) in Class Library as a resource and then serve them with HttpModule. It works well and I have common scripts in only one place, only downside is that you must compile project when you change javascript and some developers aren't use to that and they don't like it :)

So simply add javascript file to Class Library and mark it as a Embedded Resource in build action (right click on js file in Solution Explorer), and then just serve it with HttpHandler or generic ashx handler. You will have to have some code "asking" for your scripts via that hanlder, I do that from that same Class Library code that needs Javascript code on client, via Page.RegisterClientScriptInclude. You can get current page instance from Class Library with this:

```
  if (HttpContext.Current.Handler is Page)
    Page currPage = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
```